# minimization on a u-shape curve

Tags: calculus, geometry

There is a function $y=f(x)$, $f'(x)<0$, for all values of $x$. There is another function $y=g(x)$, $g'(x)>0$, for all values of $x$. There is a third function $y=h(x)$, which is u-shaped.

We assume that both $f-h$ and $g-h$ have minimum points on $R$.

$x_1$ is the point where $f-h$ is minimum (i.e. $f'=h'$). $x_2$ is the point where $g-h$ is minimum (i.e. $g'=h'$) .

We have to prove that the value of $(x_2-x_1)$ depends on the sharpness of the u-shaped curve $h(x)$ i.e. the sharper the curve, the closer are the points $x_1$ and $x_2$.

The flatter the curve $h(x)$, the further are the points $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f-h$ will not necessarily have a minimum on $\mathbb{R}$. For example, take $f(x)=-x$ and $h(x)=x^2$. Then $f(x)-h(x)=-x(1+x)$ which is a maximum at $x=-1/2$ and no minimum. The same is true of $g-h$. There can also be many points where the derivatives of these functions are zero.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out!  let me modify the question by adding the assumption that both f-h and g-h have minimum points on R. (yes, there can  be many points where the derivatives of these functions are zero..for eg., the u-shape might have a flat bottom...is that a problem ? )